# WordPress site migration

Tags: wordpress, localhost, database-migration

I moved site from online server to my local server. I changed in db links from my live domain into my localhost folder.

When I open site on my localhost it just shows me a blank page without any error report.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the reason ?

Thanks,
Denis

Comment: you can debug your site by adding  `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` on your wp-config.php to see any error on wordpress

Answer (score 0):

have you changed the db credentials in wp-config file in the root folder? There is a plugin duplicator:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/
use this plugin to migrate wordpress website from one server to another.